# Firebase for web: telling whether user is logged in or not

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a web app built on Firebase's web library. I want to restrict some pages to only users who are logged in.

This code triggers when firebase detects the user is logged in, which is good.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
  console.log('User is logged in');
});
```

But I can't get anything to reliably check whether the user is *not* logged in without leaving the page before the above code has a chance to check...

```
var check_firebaseReady == false;
function local_initApp() {
  if (check_firebaseReady == false) {
    if (typeof firebase !== 'undefined') {
      check_firebaseReady = true;
      console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser); //not reliable becuase it may return an empty user before it has a chance to get an existing user
    } 
    setTimeout(function () {
      local_initApp();
    }, 300);
  }
}
local_initApp();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think for single page apps, you have to use the `onAuthStateChanged` listener and enforce access via security rules on specific data. If you want to block access to a complete page, you are better off using a cookie system. Firebase Auth provides that option: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies

With cookies, you would check and verify the cookie server side, otherwise, not serve the page and show some error or redirect to login page instead.